# How to create multiple toggles with functional component with React?

Tags: reactjs, toggle

How to create multiple toggles with functional component with React?

1. I already Google and I found that most of solution are class components method.
   I tried to declare name in the button but it still not working.
2. Also, another question is I tried to separate the component in other file, but I met a problem that the item in 'li' tag they won't separate.

I'm beginner in React. Please kindly help.

Here is the codesandbox Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/08-29-reactpractice-forked-58cghe?file=/src/Title.js:0-27

Comment: You need own state for each toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the state of both modals in one state

```js
  const [showItems, setShowItems] = useState(false);
```

You can assign each modal it's own state

```js
  const [showServices, setShowServices] = useState(false);
  const [showContact, setShowContact] = useState(false);
```

This is the more common practice in my experience. However if you did want to maintain both modals in one state you could do the following

```js
const [itemToShow,setItemToShow] = useState('')
```

And then assign the selected modal state when onClick

```js
   <button name="services" onClick={() => setItemToShow("services")}>
          {itemsToShow === services ? "Hide" : "Expand"}
   </button>
```

N.B: I changed 'Expend' to 'Expand'